# How to access a 'net' socket in Angular Controller?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, controller

I'm trying to access a socket (right now i'm going with 'net' sockets, because it works on its own) through an angular controller.

the idea is: i press a button on the frontend, which fires a function that sends and receives messages from the server to another device i want to control.

but i can't seem to get the socket "into" the controller scope.

socket works fine on its own

```
function sendCommand(command) {
console.log ("trying to connect to "+ Host +":"+ Port);
// Connect to the box:
var client =  new net.Socket();
client.connect(Port, Host, Connected);
client.on('data', InputReceived);
client.on('end', Disconnected);
client.on('error', printError);
client.write(command + '\n');  
client.end();
}
```

this sends and receives the messages just fine.

but now i want to do the same from my angular app, so i'll have to get that socket into the controller somehow.. but i don't know how.

i tried

```
.factory('Socket', function(){
var socket = require('net').socket.notify('create', true);
})
```

but "require is not defined" (since it's not run inside node i guess).

How can i create a socket that is usable within the controller scope (or any other way to accomplish this)?

Comment: Is the controller being executed (server-side) by Node.js? The Node platform's `net` module and TCP sockets in general aren't compatible with or made available to client-side JavaScript. For a web-based equivalent, look into WebSockets.

Comment: the "box" doesn't support websockets, it needs a raw tcp socket, that's why i thought simple net was the way to go.
concerning the controller being executed by node.. i sure hope so..
is it possible that it isn't? how to check?

i WANT it to run on the server. i just want to issue the commands to it from the front-end. but i can't reach the socket object

Answer (score 0):

You have already registered the socket as a service when you wrote,

```
.factory('Socket', function(){
    var socket = require('net').socket.notify('create', true);
})
```

now what you have to do is pass the service you registered into the controller.
For example if your module name is app you can write,

```
.controller (your_ctrl_name, function (Socket) {
   //Write the functionality you want to perform inside the controller
}
```

Now within this controller block you have access to the Socket you have defined earlier.